# Lists of Pages to Block for SharePoint 2016 Public Facing Site

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have enabled the ViewFormPagesLockDown feature on my site this help to prevent to access the lits and library pages. However still can able to access the SharePoint Webservice pages like (/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx, etc)

Please advise the list of pages to need a block for SharePoint 2016 Public Facing Site. So that will use URL Scan to block all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

To block anonymous access to pages in _layouts directory and web services in _vti_bin directory, add below given xml in web.config

```
<location path="_layouts">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
```

and

```
<location path="_vti_bin">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
```

Reference - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/how-to-secure-external-anonymous-access-to-sharepoint-2010-sites/

You can find all the list of web services under _vti_bin [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862916(v=office.12).aspx) and list of pages under _layouts [here](https://sharepointtechnicalsupport.com/2017/02/25/sharepoint-shortcut-url-and-hidden-list/)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a list of SharePoint  System and application pages?

Comment: updated my answer with links to articles listing all pages